# How to load a CSV file using file_selector and callbacks in Taipy

Tags: python, csv, taipy

I have a newbie Taipy question related to file_selector/callbacks.

I want to use the *file_selector* to load a CSV file. Here is what I am currently doing:

```py
contents = """
<|file_selector|label=Upload dataset|on_action=load_csv_file|extensions=.csv|>
"""

def load_csv_file(selection):
    dataset = pd.read_csv(selection)
```

However, the selection is not the selected file, but an (empty) *State* object…
Am I missing something?
How should I get the selected path so that I can do something with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can found below a small code snippet to help you utilize this control effectively.

The *file_selector* is linked to a Python variable (here, *path*). This variable represents the path of the selected file in the *file_selector*. The current value of *path* can be accessed through the State object, as shown below. The State object holds all GUI variables used by the application. For more information, refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.taipy.io/en/release-2.1/getting_started/getting-started-gui/step_03/ReadMe/#multi-user-state).

When a file is uploaded via the *file_selector*, the *load_csv_file* function is executed. The selected file's path, `state.path`, is used to read the CSV.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
import pandas as pd

path = None
data = None

md = """
<|{path}|file_selector|label=Upload dataset|on_action=load_csv_file|extensions=.csv|>

<|{data}|table|rebuild|>
"""

def load_csv_file(state):
    state.data = pd.read_csv(state.path)
    print(state.data)

Gui(md).run()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this example could be improved to also display data as a table in UI. I did `from taipy.gui import Gui
import pandas as pd

path = None
data = pd.DataFrame()

md = """<|{path}|file_selector|label=Upload dataset|on_action=load_csv_file|extensions=.csv|>

<|{data}|table|>
"""

def load_csv_file(state):
    state.data = pd.read_csv(state.path)

Gui(md).run()` but it didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try `<|{data}|table|rebuild|>` in your md variable.

Comment: You can edit your answers using the [edit] link right below them.